# SonarQube - Unable to load component class

Tags: maven, sonarqube, continuous-integration, devops

I keep receiving this issue (Build failure) when I add a random exclude in SonarQube.

I don't know why this occurs and it still throws a build failure irrespective of what what I exclude.

This used to work before I upgraded SonarQube from 7.4 to 7.5.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project root: Unable to load component class
>   org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor: Unable to load
>   component class
>   org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.scanner.IssueExclusionsLoader: Unable
>   to load component class
>   org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.IssueExclusionPatternInitializer:
>   Exclusions > Issues : Invalid format. The first field does not define
>   a resource pattern: ,squid:S00119,* -> [Help 1]

Comment: Please add a screen with the rule configuration(`your-sq-server/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS00119&q=S00119`).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed my issue by adding in SonarQube, not only the squid:S00119 but also the what file pattern to search for. I only added squid:S00119 and that is why it wasn't enough. You need also to specify what file.